# Batch command to delete every Directory and File in specified Directory in Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I tried setting up a task in windows task scheduler. What i want to do is delete every file and directory in a given directory which was not modified in the last 30 days.
So i set the task up as following:

Program/script:
`ForFiles`

Arguments:
`/p "C:\...\baseFolder" /s /d -30 /c "cmd /c del /q @file"`

But this caused only the files to get wiped. Furthermore in the process the modify-date of the folders was refreshed. How i can also delete the directories residing in `C:\...\baseFolder`?

UPDATE:

My current approach looks like this:

```
ForFiles /p "C:\...\baseFolder" /s /d -30 /c "cmd /c del /q @file" && FORFILES /S /D -30 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rmdir /S /Q "C:\...\baseFolder"
```

Executing this batch returns `No files found with the specified search criteria` eventhough there are Directories modified more than 30 days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were wanting to check each sub tree directory individually, then use the initial `/S` option, but do not perform a recursive removal of the directories. That will remove all directories which do not directly contain files modified within the last 30 days. Once that is completed, you'd then need to delete all remaining files not modified within the previous 30 days too.
The logical problem with your updated code methodology is that, if you delete files first, the modification date of all of their parent subdirectories may be updated to reflect todays date, meaning that no subdirectories would pass the second command date filter.

For example:

```batch-file
%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "C:\...\baseFolder" /S /D -30 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C If @IsDir==TRUE RD /Q @File"
%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "C:\...\baseFolder" /S /D -30 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C If @IsDir==FALSE Del /A /F @File"
```

As this is a batch file, there is no need whatsoever to try to chain the two separate commands onto one line.

*Please note however, that you may end up with some empty directories, which have not been catered for in the example above.*

Answer (score 1):

It's advised to use `del` for files (as you're doing) and `rmdir` for directories (check `rmdir /?` for the usage).

Comment: edited the command accordingly into the question. Still can't get it to work.

Comment: Replace "rmdir" by "echo", so that you see if your command finds them. If this is ok, then you can start trying to delete them.